# Overwriting a csv file on C drive using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to overwrite a CSV file using

```
write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").option("header","true").save("C:\\location\\demo.csv")
```

But it is creating a new folder of name `demo.csv` instead of overwriting.
I am new to spark and I am trying to implement this on windows.

Comment: This is how Spark behaves. You can't specify a file name. If you want to write to a specific file on a local file system, use `java.nio._` API.

Comment: Can we over write it in linux?? @philantrovert

Comment: You can write the file to HDFS and then use a shell script to get it on to your local file system and rename it. Can be done via spark as well but you will have to submit your JAR in client mode if you're on YARN.